# Could use some advice on making a calculation page in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have studied rails for some time now and everywhere I look, the books teach you how to create blog like applications.

But now I would like to create an application, where you have for instance a form to choose how many calculations I want to do and a form to choose what type of calculations should they be.
After that I would insert numbers into newly created forms and the app would calculate them and print the anwer.

Now I really don't see, how I can do this without putting the numbers inserted into a DB and then calculating with them, printing the answer and then deleting the DB entries.
Seems like a very clumsy way doing it.

Anyone have some advice on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Just to clarify, I am not really looking for help in writing code, just some guidance in the approach of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see this is: you create a dropdown with possible calculation options and enhance it with javascript (or ajax if it is complicated) to insert needed fields. Then you have all the data in one form, you send it to action, do calculations and displays them.

Comment: I will try and see how it goes.